# How can I change the WooCommerce add to cart button, specifically the "proceed to cart" contents in the ::after?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Please forgive me for any duplicate questions or not asking the question correctly.. I am new to WooCommerce. I'd like to use WooCommerce their script to provide feedback after the add to cart button has been clicked, but I have to alter the HTML output of this script. I do not know how to do that.

The button I am talking about is the add to cart button found on https://melvinosengawebdesign.nl/product-categorie/bedrukken/flyers/a6/

After clicking the button it will make some CSS changes to the button which are fine, but it also adds a "Proceed to cart" link in the ::after. I would like to change this around so it gets added in for example a span or a paragraph, and I want to change the text too.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the button JavaScript adds the class 'added' to the button, so there is some rules in css appears:

```
.woocommerce a.button.added::after {
  font-family: WooCommerce;
  content: '\e017';
  margin-left: .53em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

If you need to remove this - just add to style.css

```
body.woocommerce a.button.added::after {
  content: none;
}
```

If you need to add some HTML to the button after clicking, use JS like this:

```
$('.add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).after('<span>Added</span>');
});
```